# Excel Formula (or VBA) to Calculate Remaining Interest on Loan mid-term

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon!

I have 13000 loan records. My sheet has the following headers
| OrigLoanAmt | RemainingBalance | OrigLoanTermInMonths | RemainingTermInMonths | RegularMonthlyPmt | InterestRate |

What is a formula or VBA that will take the information I have, throw it into an amortization table, look at the current loan period, and output the total remaining interest scheduled on a loan assuming the borrower has made, and will continue to make, the minimum monthly payment for the entire term?

Example: 19 months ago I borrowed $30,000 on a 48 month term with a 2.99% rate. After I make my next payment, my new balance will be $17,933.87. From that point, per the amortization schedule, I will still have $655.19 interest to pay over the remaining 28 months.

So, my question restated would be: What formula, or VBA script, could I use to calculate that $655 figure for 13,000 loan records?

Thank you very much for your consideration on this issue!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [CUMIPMT() Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CUMIPMT-function-61067bb0-9016-427d-b95b-1a752af0e606)

```
=CUMIPMT(0.0299/12,48,30000,21,48,0)
```

Comment: This is the best answer possible; the function is purpose-built in Excel for exactly this calculation.

Comment: May you be blessed with a plentiful supply of great beer, frequent hugs and general happiness for you and your family.

Comment: @bteague in a few minutes you will be able to mark this as correct by clicking the green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  Please come back and do so.  It will mark this question as answered.